# Spring Session Boot Error - No session repository could be auto-configured, check your configuration (session store type is 'jdbc')

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-session

I am trying to create a simple Spring Boot Session project. It's the basic setup from Spring Initializr. I am getting following errors:

```
2018-06-20 12:59:24.318  INFO 8108 --- [           main] c.j.s.SpringSessionExampleApplication    : Starting SpringSessionExampleApplication on pankaj with PID 8108 (/Users/pankaj/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.4.RELEASE/Spring-Session-Example/target/classes started by pankaj in /Users/pankaj/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.4.RELEASE/Spring-Session-Example)
2018-06-20 12:59:24.329  INFO 8108 --- [           main] c.j.s.SpringSessionExampleApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-06-20 12:59:24.372  INFO 8108 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@39de3d36: startup date [Wed Jun 20 12:59:24 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/Users/pankaj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-06-20 12:59:25.208  INFO 8108 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-06-20 12:59:25.226  INFO 8108 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-06-20 12:59:25.226  INFO 8108 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-06-20 12:59:25.230  INFO 8108 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/pankaj/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2018-06-20 12:59:25.297  INFO 8108 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-06-20 12:59:25.297  INFO 8108 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 931 ms
2018-06-20 12:59:25.407  INFO 8108 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-06-20 12:59:25.411  INFO 8108 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-06-20 12:59:25.411  INFO 8108 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-06-20 12:59:25.411  INFO 8108 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-06-20 12:59:25.411  INFO 8108 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-06-20 12:59:25.500  INFO 8108 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-06-20 12:59:25.687  INFO 8108 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@39de3d36: startup date [Wed Jun 20 12:59:24 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-20 12:59:25.731  INFO 8108 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/messages],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.HomeController.saveMessage(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-06-20 12:59:25.732  INFO 8108 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.HomeController.home(org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
2018-06-20 12:59:25.734  INFO 8108 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-06-20 12:59:25.735  INFO 8108 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-06-20 12:59:25.757  INFO 8108 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-06-20 12:59:25.758  INFO 8108 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-06-20 12:59:25.844  INFO 8108 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
2018-06-20 12:59:26.005  WARN 8108 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionAutoConfiguration$ServletSessionRepositoryValidator': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionRepositoryUnavailableException: No session repository could be auto-configured, check your configuration (session store type is 'jdbc')
2018-06-20 12:59:26.006  INFO 8108 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-06-20 12:59:26.008  INFO 8108 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-06-20 12:59:26.023  INFO 8108 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-06-20 12:59:26.032 ERROR 8108 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionAutoConfiguration$ServletSessionRepositoryValidator': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionRepositoryUnavailableException: No session repository could be auto-configured, check your configuration (session store type is 'jdbc')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:424) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1700) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.journaldev.spring.SpringSessionExampleApplication.main(SpringSessionExampleApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionRepositoryUnavailableException: No session repository could be auto-configured, check your configuration (session store type is 'jdbc')
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionAutoConfiguration$AbstractSessionRepositoryValidator.checkSessionRepository(SessionAutoConfiguration.java:257) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

My `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SpringSessionDB
spring.datasource.username=pankaj
spring.datasource.password=pankaj

spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I am not sure what is missing here?

Comment: I suspect you need `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` to pull in the jdbc dependencies. Else add the full stacktrace (as this appears to be a snippet).

Comment: tried with it, still same error. Added complete exception stack trace.

Comment: Try running with debug enabled, that gives you a report on what auto configuration failed.

Comment: Tried to run in Debug Mode, no useful information there also.

Comment: That should give some information on what failed to auto-configure (it will give you a report). The only thing I can think of is that it failed to configure the datasource.

Comment: I have uploaded it to GitHub, could you please check once? https://github.com/journaldev/journaldev/tree/master/Spring/Spring-Session-Example

Comment: It's not showing any errors related to DataSource.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing the `spring-session-jdbc` dependency so the `JdbcOperationsSessionRepository` isn't present on the classpath. Your dependency management provides only `spring-session-core` dependency, which provides only Spring Session core API - the concrete `SessionRepository` implementations are placed in dedicated modules i.e. `spring-session-data-redis`, `spring-session-jdbc`, `spring-session-hazelcast` etc.

Once you do that, you can also remove the `spring.session.store-type` configuration property. As long as you have a single `SessionRepository` implementation on the classpath, Spring Boot will be able to deduce which one to auto-configure without you having to provide `spring.session.store-type`.

Having said that, Initializr should be able to include `spring-session-jdbc` for you however I believe you originally only selected `Web`, `Session` and `MySQL` options when creating project on Initialzr. Together with `Session` option, you should also select the store you intend to use (like `JDBC` in this case) so the Initializr can include the required Spring Session module.

On a final note, the arrangement with Spring Session modules changed in Spring Session 2.0, as previously all the code and `SessionRepository` implementations were placed in `spring-session` artifact which doesn't exist anymore in Spring Session 2.0. You can learn more about this in in [the reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#modules) and have been mentioned in the [`2.0.0.RELEASE` announcement](https://spring.io/blog/2018/01/16/spring-session-2-0-0-released).

Comment: Thanks, I use Spring Initializr and selected Spring Session. There was no option of suggestion to include spring-session-jdbc as well. Appreciate the clear explanation.

Comment: Yes, there's no explicit option on Initializr to select which Spring Session store to use, as you have to select the data store option separately. FWIW, I agree this isn't ideal. Note that you can see the code that handles Spring Session module selection [here](https://github.com/spring-io/initializr/blob/master/initializr-service/src/main/java/io/spring/initializr/service/extension/SpringSessionRequestPostProcessor.java). You could also consider raising an issue with Initializr and describe how you feel user experience could be improved.